# Did F. B. Meyer publish a book about the Second Epistle of Peter?

Tags: resource-request, books, 2-peter

F. B. Meyer (Frederick Brotherton) published a book named "Tried by fire: Expositions of the First Epistle of Peter".

Did he publish expositions of the Second Epistle of Peter? If so, what's the name of the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From various list of works that I could find, [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._B._Meyer#Works), [*thriftbooks*](https://www.thriftbooks.com/a/fb-meyer/294110/), [*archive.org*](https://archive.org/search?query=creator%3A%22Meyer%2C+F.+B.+%28Frederick+Brotherton%29%2C+1847-1929%22&page=3&sort=title), and [Pioneer Library](https://olddeadguys.com/2021/11/25/free-books-by-f-b-meyer-60/) (the most complete list), **there doesn't appear to be an exposition for 2 Peter**.

He did write expositions for the [Gospel of John](https://archive.org/details/gospelofjohnlife00meye/page/n5/mode/2up), [Philippians](https://archive.org/details/epistletophilipp0000meye), and [Hebrews](https://archive.org/details/TheWayIntoTheHoliest) as well as books on [Abraham](https://archive.org/details/abrahamorobedien0000meye), [Jacob](https://archive.org/details/israelprincewith0000meye), [Joseph](https://archive.org/details/josephbelovedhat0000meye), [Moses](https://archive.org/details/mosesservantofgo00meye), [Samuel](https://archive.org/details/cu31924029310251), [David](https://archive.org/details/davidshepherdpsa00meyeuoft), [Elijah](https://archive.org/details/elijahsecretofhi0000meye), [Jeremiah](https://archive.org/details/jeremiahpriestpr0000meye_b2r2), [John the Baptist](https://archive.org/details/johnbaptist00meye), [Paul](https://archive.org/details/paulservantofjesmeye00meye), and [Peter](https://archive.org/details/cu31924007757697/page/n11/mode/2up).

You may find references to 2 Peter from his non-Exposition works:

1. Book on Peter: [Peter: Fisherman, Disciple, Apostle](https://archive.org/details/peterfishermandi00meye)
2. Through the Bible day by Day: A Devotional Commentary Vol 7 (Philippians - Revelation) [Pages 145-154](https://archive.org/details/throughbibledayb0000meye/page/144/mode/2up) (The Second Epistle of Peter)
3. Our Daily Homily, Vol. 5: Matthew - Revelation [Pages 228-230](https://archive.org/details/ourdailyhomily05meye/page/228/mode/2up) (3 days covering 2 Pet 1:11, 2 Pet 2:9, and 2 Pet 3:8)